# How to remove everything after a space in each of my array objects in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have two arrays containing letters and numbers for each array object. example: "Matthew 20897". I want to delete the numbers from every array object so I can compare both arrays and see if they have any words/names in common. I tried doing an explode to get rid of the space but I get an error saying the explode() expects parameter 2 to be a string.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
//simple read file and print
$boy = array();
$girl = array();
$connectionBoy = fopen("boynames.txt", "r") or die("Can't open boynames.txt file.");
$connectionGirl = fopen("girlnames.txt", "r") or die("Can't open girlnames.txt file.");

while(! feof($connectionBoy)){   //while it is not the end of the file
    
    $word = fgets($connectionBoy);  //read a record
    $word = rtrim($word); //gets rid of end of record char
    $boy[] = $word;
}

while(! feof($connectionGirl)){   //while it is not the end of the file
    
    $word2 = fgets($connectionGirl);  //read a record
    $word2 = rtrim($word2); //gets rid of end of record char
    $girl[] = $word2;
}

fclose($connectionBoy);
 echo "Number of names in the boynames file are ".sizeof($boy)."<br>";
 echo "Number of names in the boynames file are ".sizeof($girl);
 
 $itemBoy = explode(" ",$boy);
 $itemGirl = explode(" ",$girl);
 
 $result =array_intersect($itemBoy,$itemGirl);
 print_r($result);
```

Also, both arrays have 1000 records stored in them so I would have to remove everything after the space for all items in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use rtrim().
echo rtrim('     Removendo Espaços     ');

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rtrim.php
http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/remover-espacos-php-trim-ltrim-e-rtrim

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

> explode — Split a string by a string

explode takes a string and splits it into an array. $boy and $girl are already arrays.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you could do get rid of the numbers inside your loops doing something like this:

```
$splitWord2 = explode(' ', $word2);
$girl[] = $splitWord2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I'm seeing you are using `explode` function in the wrong place. It should be in the `while loop` as string should be exploded there to get the first word of name.I have updated your code.

```
<?php

$boy = array();
$girl = array();
$connectionBoy = fopen("boynames.txt", "r") or die("Can't open boynames.txt file.");
$connectionGirl = fopen("girlnames.txt", "r") or die("Can't open girlnames.txt file.");

while(! feof($connectionBoy)){   //while it is not the end of the file
    
    $line = fgets($connectionBoy);  //read a record
    $line = trim($line); //gets rid of end of record char
    $parts = explode(" ",$line);
    $boy[] = $parts[0];
}

while(! feof($connectionGirl)){   //while it is not the end of the file
    
    $line = fgets($connectionGirl);  //read a record
    $line = trim($line); //gets rid of end of record char
    $parts = explode(" ",$line);
    $girl[] = $parts[0];
}

fclose($connectionBoy);
fclose($connectionGirl);

echo "Number of names in the boynames file are ".sizeof($boy)."<br>";
echo "Number of names in the boynames file are ".sizeof($girl);

$result =array_intersect($boy,$girl);
print_r($result);

?>
```